# Querying average and rolling 12 month average

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, window-functions, getdate

I want to be able to find out the average per month and rolling average over the last 12 months of a count for the number of changes per customer.

```
SELECT 
    crq_requested_by_company as 'Customer',
    COUNT(crq_number) as 'Number of Changes'
FROM 
    change_information ci1
GROUP BY 
    crq_requested_by_company
```

At the moment I am just doing the count of the total and my results look like this

```
crq_requested_by_company    count   
A                             4
B                             2
C                             2269
D                             7696
E                             110
F                             91
G                             33
```

The date column I will be using is called 'start_date'.

I assume `GETDATE()` will be needed to work out the rolling average for the last 12 months.

**Additional info after comments:**

Using the code

```
;WITH CTE as
(
SELECT 
crq_requested_by_company as Customer,
COUNT(crq_number) Nuc,
dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, crq_start_date),0) m
FROM 
change_information ci1
WHERE
crq_start_date >= dateadd(month,datediff(month, 0,getdate()) - 12,0)
GROUP BY 
crq_requested_by_company,
datediff(month, 0, crq_start_date)
)
SELECT 
Customer,
avg(Nuc) over (partition by Customer order by m) running_avg,
m start_month,
avg(Nuc) over (partition by Customer) simply_average
FROM
CTE
ORDER BY Customer, start_month
```

This gives the results

```
Customer    running_avg start_month      simply_average
A                8      01/01/2016 00:00 13
A                10     01/02/2016 00:00 13
A                10     01/03/2016 00:00 13
A                11     01/04/2016 00:00 13
A                14     01/05/2016 00:00 13
A                13     01/06/2016 00:00 13
B                1      01/01/2016 00:00 1
C                3      01/01/2016 00:00 2
C                3      01/02/2016 00:00 2
C                2      01/03/2016 00:00 2
C                2      01/04/2016 00:00 2
C                2      01/05/2016 00:00 2
C                2      01/06/2016 00:00 2
```

It needs to look like this so the average of the results above - the average of the 6 months above (I only currently have 6 months of data and needs to be 12 eventually)

```
Customer   avg_of_running_avg
A          11
B          1
C          2
```

Comment: Simple average or Day Weighted Average.

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2835541).

Comment: @JohnCappelletti 1) just a simple average count per month 2) a rolling average of the count per month over the last 12 months

Comment: so you simply need the average of the running_avg result ? That should be fixed by the change I made just now

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it should work for sqlserver 2012 using running average:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
SELECT 
    crq_requested_by_company as Customer,
    COUNT(crq_number) Nuc,
    dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, start_date),0) m
FROM 
    change_information ci1
WHERE
  start_date >= dateadd(month,datediff(month, 0,getdate()) - 12,0)
GROUP BY 
    crq_requested_by_company,
    datediff(month, 0, start_date)
)
SELECT 
  Customer,
  avg(Nuc) over (partition by Customer order by m) running_avg,
  m start_month,
  avg(Nuc) over (partition by Customer) simply_average
FROM
  CTE
ORDER BY Customer, start_month
```

Comment: That gives the count average each month. I now need the average of the last 12 months of that.

The result looks like this

Customer running_avg start_month
A 8 01/01/2016 00:00
A 10 01/02/2016 00:00
A 10 01/03/2016 00:00
A 11 01/04/2016 00:00
A 14 01/05/2016 00:00
A 13 01/06/2016 00:00
B 1 01/01/2016 00:00
C 3 01/01/2016 00:00
C 3 01/02/2016 00:00
C 2 01/03/2016 00:00
C 2 01/04/2016 00:00
C 2 01/05/2016 00:00
C 2 01/06/2016 00:00

I need it to look like this 

Customer avg_of_running_avg
A 11
B 1
C 2

Comment: @DeanFlaherty maybe you should make that part of the question

Comment: I have now added it above